# Visual Studio 2010 C# Double

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, double

I've had problems while converting Decimal to Double in C#.
Instead of 0.3 I was getting 0.2999999999999

When I debug a little bit, I've seen that conversion is not the problem.

See the print screen and my watch list?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv2gU.png

Anyone has idea?

EDIT: 
Answer: It was some strange behavior of Visual Studio 2010. 
After restarting everything is fine.

Comment: Floating point values

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: As it is, this question cannot be answered. 0.2999999999999 is as valid a Double value as 0.3. Without context, noone can tell you why these values you are watching are "wrong".

Comment: My Question is more: How application context can affect simple adding 0.3 in watch list to be equal to 0.29999.... In  new console applicaiton this is working as it should

Comment: Do you mean that you create a "value double foo = 0.3;", you watch it and the watch says 0.2999999999999? If so, you can simplify your question, removing the reference to a conversion and stressing that you are concerned about a watch screen.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: Correct

Comment: Write the following code: "double foo = 0.3; Debug.Assert(foo == 0.3);" and see that the assert does not fail. That will guarantee that your variable is equal to 0.3. Then your only problem is with the watch and your question should be fully edited to explain that.

Comment: Edited: after restarting the VS2010 everything is fine. Strange, very strange..

Answer (score 2):

`0.3` has an infinite Representation, when stored binary: `(0.) 00111111 11010011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 .....` No matter if you store it with 32,64 or 128 bit, it will cut off at some point.

When converting that back to a double you will loose accuracy. that's why you are getting 0.2999999999...

This is not a bug, it is simple impossible to store infinite accuracy.

Comment: It was some strange behavior of Visual Studio 2010. After restarting everything is fine.

Comment: Please note the standard for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point IEEE-754

Answer (score 1):

that behavior is common for double, as it is a [floating binary type](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx).
These two types save the values completely different in memory such as:

**in float, the computer saves a number like this**

```
10001.10010110011
```

**However in decimal, it is stored like this**

```
12345.65789
```

Which can cause small difference in the numbers, for example:

**in float:**

```
0.1 = 0.09999
```

**In decimal**

```
0.l = 0.1
```